# Join 2 arrays using LINQ with condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, linq

I have two arrays converted from datatables.

I need to join the two arrays on a condition and then databind the final results to a ListView.

The first array has only one column, and the second has several. I need to join them where column txtItemA on searchResults is equal to txtItemNumber on queryResults column.

I'm not sure even if I'm on the right track. Visual Studio is showing a redline under searchresults in this line....

```
var showResults = from a in searchResults
```

My code...

```
ArrayList searchResults = new ArrayList();
foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt2.Rows)
    searchResults.Add(string.Join(";", dataRow.ItemArray.Select(item => item.ToString())));

ArrayList queryResults = new ArrayList();
foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt2.Rows)
    queryResults.Add(string.Join(";", dataRow.ItemArray.Select(item => item.ToString())));


var showResults = from a in searchResults
                  join b in queryResults on b.txtItemNumber equals a.txtItemA
                  select new
                  {
                      newseries = searchResults.newseries,
                      series = searchResults.series
                  };

ListView1.DataSource = showResults.ToArray();
ListView1.DataBind();
```

I tried using this code from Gilad Green...

```
List<string> searchResults = new List<string>();
foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt2.Rows)
    searchResults.Add(string.Join(";", dataRow.ItemArray.Select(item => item.ToString())));

List<string> queryResults = new List<string>();
foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt2.Rows)
    queryResults.Add(string.Join(";", dataRow.ItemArray.Select(item => item.ToString())));

var showResults = searchResults.Where(item => queryResults.Contains(item.txtItemA)
    .Select(item => new {
                            newseries = item.newseries,
                            series = item.series
                        }));
```

I still cant get this to work..

Errors on item in the line.....Select(item => new {

parameter or local variable cannot have the same name as a method type parameter

and txtItemA

string does contain a definition for txtItemA and no extension method....

Comment: How are you joining on `b.txtItemNumber equals a.txtItemA` when both `b` and `a` are strings?

Comment: Are you using a typed dataRow? If so can you post an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, It uses standard DataRows and I'm guessing the field names based on your sample code.

```
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

        var showResults = dt2.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Join(dt2.Rows.Cast<DataRow>(), a => a.Field<string>("txtItemNumber"), b => b.Field<string>("txtItemA"), (a, b) => new
        {
            newseries = a.Field<string>("newseries"),
            series = a.Field<string>("series")
        });

        ListView1.DataSource = showResults.ToArray();
        ListView1.DataBind();
```